# How to use the copied line reference after "Copy Reference" in Android Studio or Intellij IDEA

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio we can Use **Copy Reference** `(ctrl+alt+shift+C)` and it gives a reference to current line but I'm not sure how to use this reference as a click-able link in the comment of another file.

I'm looking for a way to easy navigate to that reference inside IDE so `JavaDoc` link functions which works outside IDE can't be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fastest way I found to navigate to that reference in Android Studio:

Select the pasted reference in the comment and <kbd>ctrl+shift+N</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
It auto fills the box so doesn't need to copy the address, this will navigate to the referenced line.

Since the functionality is already there it seems a good candidate for writing a plugin to detect address automatically and turns it to links.

**Update:**
You can record a macro and make this almost automatic. Edit>Macros and this keystroke sequence:
`End
Shift+Home
Ctrl+Shift+N`

Assign a keybinding to your macro in setting>keymap for example <kbd>ctrl+shft+G</kbd>. The caret must be in the line you've pasted the reference of course.